# Line Following Robot using JavaScript, Arduino and Q-Learning

Tags: javascript, arduino, robot, q-learning

I'm hoping to create a line following robot that uses Q-Learning.  My intention is to use/build a  robot based upon Arduino parts, while using JavaScript for the programming side.

At the time of writing I've been googling around a bit, and think that this is a feasible project.  However it will be my first attempt at programming JavaScript and building an Arduino robot, so I'd appreciate any pointers you guys might have.

I'm not asking you to solve the problem, but rather highlight any showstoppers that I may encounter.  I have no previous JavaScript or Arduino experience!

Thanks for your time,

Mark

Comment: I don't think this question is specific enough for StackOverflow.  I'd suggest you change your question to ask something more detailed about one aspect of your project that can be answered in a few paragraphs (per Stackoverflow guidelines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple how to:

- buy an Arduino
- get familiar with the ide and how it works
- leave the ide behind [if you don't like it](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project)
- build the robot
- write the Arduino code to follow lines
- then move on to js if you will.

having no experience in js and arduino whatsoever is dangerous and you'll find yourself with too much to learn.

start small, try, fail, ask questions and get to know your tools before trying to build a nuclear power plant.

EDIT: besides js doesn't work as is on Arduino, it is c++. So you'll either need to use something like johnny-five and firmata or build your own interface with node.js.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I think that you have a good point.  I will probably get a line following robot that works out of the box and focus on the JavaScript side.